# Allowing single and double quotes, and 'enter' to be expressed

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm developing a forum through PHP and MySql. I've noticed that when I enter in a reply, special characters like the single and double quotes often come out as \' or \" (respectively). I also notice that the enter key doesn't get expressed either. For example:

```
If
I
Enter
This
In
The
Text
Box
```

and the following string gets posted, this comes out instead:

```
If I Enter This In The Text Box
```

I was wondering if there was a function or if statement I can use--excuse my ignorance, I'm a bit new to PHP.

I'm also quite concerned that allowing such characters to pass through might make my website vulnerable to SQL injections. I've already used the mysql_real_escape_string on queries that require user input (e.g. registering, logging in, posting, etc.), but was wondering if it'll affect them at all. Another question, say I added BBCode functionality onto my website as well--will it make my website prone to SQL injections on top of all of that as well?

Thanks.

Comment: The first 'If I Enter This In The Text Box' is supposed to have a line break after each consecutive word.

Comment: You should post the code you are using to store and retrieve the information in and from the database.

Comment: Browsers ignore whitespace, unless told not to (using either `<pre></pre>` or the equivalent CSS styling).